# Text load after image has loaded

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an image in which I have to display text from the database using PHP, but when the page loads the text appears first and the image is displayed later, is there a way that I can make the image load first and text later?

Comment: Use javascript, where you populate the particular string using php.

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: Keep in mind, with a slow internet speed your page will seem unresponsive and people may leave before the image has been fully downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the image isn't set initially, just give it a `load` handler, and when triggered, apply the text in question:

```
<span id="my-element" data-text="php-text-here">


img.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const myElement = document.querySelector('#my-element');
  myElement.textContent = myElement.getAttribute('data-text');
});
```